# CRC Maxim/Dallas 1Wire in PHP

Tags: php, crc

How can i generate Crc8 dallas 1 wire in php?

i have implement a function but not success, what's wrong with the function?

i want to get '350118FE34F7C56400000C00BB010000000000000000FF44' and the result should be '2B'.

```
private $crc8_table = array(
    0x00, 0x5e, 0xbc, 0xe2, 0x61, 0x3f, 0xdd, 0x83, 0xc2, 0x9c, 0x7e, 0x20, 0xa3, 0xfd, 0x1f, 0x41,
    0x9d, 0xc3, 0x21, 0x7f, 0xfc, 0xa2, 0x40, 0x1e, 0x5f, 0x01, 0xe3, 0xbd, 0x3e, 0x60, 0x82, 0xdc,
    0x23, 0x7d, 0x9f, 0xc1, 0x42, 0x1c, 0xfe, 0xa0, 0xe1, 0xbf, 0x5d, 0x03, 0x80, 0xde, 0x3c, 0x62,
    0xbe, 0xe0, 0x02, 0x5c, 0xdf, 0x81, 0x63, 0x3d, 0x7c, 0x22, 0xc0, 0x9e, 0x1d, 0x43, 0xa1, 0xff,
    0x46, 0x18, 0xfa, 0xa4, 0x27, 0x79, 0x9b, 0xc5, 0x84, 0xda, 0x38, 0x66, 0xe5, 0xbb, 0x59, 0x07,
    0xdb, 0x85, 0x67, 0x39, 0xba, 0xe4, 0x06, 0x58, 0x19, 0x47, 0xa5, 0xfb, 0x78, 0x26, 0xc4, 0x9a,
    0x65, 0x3b, 0xd9, 0x87, 0x04, 0x5a, 0xb8, 0xe6, 0xa7, 0xf9, 0x1b, 0x45, 0xc6, 0x98, 0x7a, 0x24,
    0xf8, 0xa6, 0x44, 0x1a, 0x99, 0xc7, 0x25, 0x7b, 0x3a, 0x64, 0x86, 0xd8, 0x5b, 0x05, 0xe7, 0xb9,
    0x8c, 0xd2, 0x30, 0x6e, 0xed, 0xb3, 0x51, 0x0f, 0x4e, 0x10, 0xf2, 0xac, 0x2f, 0x71, 0x93, 0xcd,
    0x11, 0x4f, 0xad, 0xf3, 0x70, 0x2e, 0xcc, 0x92, 0xd3, 0x8d, 0x6f, 0x31, 0xb2, 0xec, 0x0e, 0x50,
    0xaf, 0xf1, 0x13, 0x4d, 0xce, 0x90, 0x72, 0x2c, 0x6d, 0x33, 0xd1, 0x8f, 0x0c, 0x52, 0xb0, 0xee,
    0x32, 0x6c, 0x8e, 0xd0, 0x53, 0x0d, 0xef, 0xb1, 0xf0, 0xae, 0x4c, 0x12, 0x91, 0xcf, 0x2d, 0x73,
    0xca, 0x94, 0x76, 0x28, 0xab, 0xf5, 0x17, 0x49, 0x08, 0x56, 0xb4, 0xea, 0x69, 0x37, 0xd5, 0x8b,
    0x57, 0x09, 0xeb, 0xb5, 0x36, 0x68, 0x8a, 0xd4, 0x95, 0xcb, 0x29, 0x77, 0xf4, 0xaa, 0x48, 0x16,
    0xe9, 0xb7, 0x55, 0x0b, 0x88, 0xd6, 0x34, 0x6a, 0x2b, 0x75, 0x97, 0xc9, 0x4a, 0x14, 0xf6, 0xa8,
    0x74, 0x2a, 0xc8, 0x96, 0x15, 0x4b, 0xa9, 0xf7, 0xb6, 0xe8, 0x0a, 0x54, 0xd7, 0x89, 0x6b, 0x35
);

public function crc8($buffer) {
    $crc = 0xFF;

    for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($buffer)/2; $i++) {
        $byte = ord(pack('H*', substr($buffer, $i * 2, 2)));
        $crc = (($this->crc8_table[($crc ^ $byte) & 0xFF]) & 0xFF);
    }

    return $crc;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That CRC is initialized with zero. Not `0xFF`.

Comment: even init with $crc = 0x00, still can't get the result '2B', any idea?

Comment: Works for me. Did you put that in a class?